# how to count rows of a table in pentaho etl, i didn't found the buttom that do the job

Tags: pentaho

I want to know how to count a row of a table in Pentaho?
A method or button on Pentaho

I didn't find the bottom that does the job,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a table input step in a transformation performing a query to output the row count, something like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM table`.

Or you have a Job Entry specific for this, it's named **Evaluate rows number in a table**.